# Fibonacci generator not giving correct results

Tags: javascript

```
function* fib() {
  a = 0;
  b = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield a;
    a = b;
    b = a + b;
  }
}

let f = fib();
let index = 0;
for(let i of f){
  if(index > 14){
    break;
  }
  console.log(i);
  index++;
}
```

Output: 
0
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `a`, so on the next line, `b = a + b` doesn't give the right calculation for the new value of `b`.

Either save it in a separate variable before reassigning, or use destructuring to swap them at once:

```js
function* fib() {
  let a = 0;
  let b = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield a;
    [a, b] = [b, a + b];
  }
}

let f = fib();
let index = 0;
for(let i of f){
  if(index > 14){
    break;
  }
  console.log(i);
  index++;
}
```

(this works because the `[b, a + b]` expression on the right is completely evaluated before the assignment for `[a, b] =` occurs)

Also, best to avoid implicitly declare global variables - consider enabling strict mode and/or using a linter, else that sort of thing may result in bugs.

Comment: It'd also be a good idea to declare all the undeclared variables.