# Generating fibonacci series using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with this code?
I am trying to solve this in the Chrome console...

```js
var array = [];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;

function fibonacci(n) {
  while (k < n) {
    var j = j + i;
    array.push[j];
    i++;
    n++;
    k++;
    console.log(array);
    return array;
  }
}
fibonacci(5);
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and explain what the problem with your approach is. Any errors in the console? Wrong result? What have you already done to debug this on your own?

Comment: This is a great time to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Using the script debugger you can place a breakpoint in your code and pause the runtime execution, allowing you to step through the execution line by line and observe the behavior and changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which line of code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values at the time?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?  (Hint: Lines like `var j = j + i;` and `return array;`, or `while (k < n)` probably don't do whatever you think they do.)

Comment: while running this code in snippets (cltr+entr),nothing is happening..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fibonacci generator not giving correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575688/fibonacci-generator-not-giving-correct-results)

Comment: @MisterJojo yeah it helped me alot..i got my mistake..Thanks alot

Comment: @Noobcoder If your problem is solved, please consider closing or deleting your question. It did not generate "real" answers, even though you got help through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

a 'classic' solution

```js
function Fibonacci(n)
  {
  let a = 1
    , b = 1
    , r = [1]  // set first one...
    ;
  for(let i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
    r.push(a+b) // new Fibonacci value
    a = b       // set a for next addition
    b = r[i]    // set b for next addition
    }
  return r
  }


console.log( Fibonacci(12).join(' - '))
```

you can also do this ;-)

```js
const Fibo=n=>Array.apply(null,{length:n}).map((c,i,t)=>(i<2)?t[i]=i+1:t[i]=t[i-2]+t[i-1])


console.log( Fibo(12).join(' - '))
```